# problems in pandas_datareader installation?

Tags: python, pandas, datareader

when I try to install pandas_datareader with the command `pip install pandas_datareader`
it gives me as output:

```
pip install pandas_datareader
Collecting pandas_datareader
  Using cached pandas_datareader-0.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (109 kB)
Collecting requests>=2.19.0
  Using cached requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting lxml
  Using cached lxml-4.9.1.tar.gz (3.4 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: pandas>=0.23 in ./env/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pandas_datareader) (1.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2020.1 in ./env/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pandas>=0.23->pandas_datareader) (2022.1)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.8.1 in ./env/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pandas>=0.23->pandas_datareader) (2.8.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.21.0 in ./env/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from pandas>=0.23->pandas_datareader) (1.22.3)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in ./env/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from requests>=2.19.0->pandas_datareader) (1.26.11)
Collecting charset-normalizer<3,>=2
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2022.6.15-py3-none-any.whl (160 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in ./env/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.8.1->pandas>=0.23->pandas_datareader) (1.16.0)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for lxml, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: lxml, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, requests, pandas_datareader
  Running setup.py install for lxml ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for lxml did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [91 lines of output]
      Building lxml version 4.9.1.
      Building without Cython.
      Building against libxml2 2.9.4 and libxslt 1.1.29
      running install
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml
      copying src/lxml/_elementpath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml
      copying src/lxml/sax.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml
      copying src/lxml/pyclasslookup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml
      copying src/lxml/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml
      copying src/lxml/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml
      copying src/lxml/doctestcompare.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml
      copying src/lxml/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml
      copying src/lxml/cssselect.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml
      copying src/lxml/ElementInclude.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/soupparser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/defs.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/_setmixin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/clean.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/_diffcommand.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/html5parser.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/formfill.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/ElementSoup.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/_html5builder.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/usedoctest.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/html
      copying src/lxml/html/diff.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/html
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/isoschematron
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/isoschematron
      copying src/lxml/etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml
      copying src/lxml/etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml
      copying src/lxml/lxml.etree.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml
      copying src/lxml/lxml.etree_api.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml
      copying src/lxml/includes/xmlerror.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/c14n.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xmlschema.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/__init__.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/schematron.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/tree.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/uri.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/etreepublic.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xpath.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/htmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xslt.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/config.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xmlparser.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/xinclude.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/dtdvalid.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/relaxng.pxd -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/lxml-version.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      copying src/lxml/includes/etree_defs.h -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/includes
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/isoschematron/resources
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng/iso-schematron.rng -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/isoschematron/resources/rng
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/XSD2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/RNG2Schtrn.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl
      creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_abstract_expand.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_dsdl_include.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_skeleton_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_svrl_for_xslt1.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/iso_schematron_message.xsl -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      copying src/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1/readme.txt -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/lxml/isoschematron/resources/xsl/iso-schematron-xslt1
      running build_ext
      building 'lxml.etree' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/src
      creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/src/lxml
      clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch arm64 -arch x86_64 -g -DCYTHON_CLINE_IN_TRACEBACK=0 -I/usr/include -Isrc -Isrc/lxml/includes -I/Users/federicoruggieri/Desktop/phyton/env/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/include/python3.10 -c src/lxml/etree.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-universal2-3.10/src/lxml/etree.o -w -flat_namespace
      xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
      Compile failed: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      creating var
      creating var/folders
      creating var/folders/kc
      creating var/folders/kc/4tv45m2j1llfjkv_fvz_tv8m0000gn
      creating var/folders/kc/4tv45m2j1llfjkv_fvz_tv8m0000gn/T
      cc -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -c /var/folders/kc/4tv45m2j1llfjkv_fvz_tv8m0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitalfahh0p.c -o var/folders/kc/4tv45m2j1llfjkv_fvz_tv8m0000gn/T/xmlXPathInitalfahh0p.o
      xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
      *********************************************************************************
      Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
      Perhaps try: xcode-select --install
      *********************************************************************************
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> lxml

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

do someone know how to solve it?

python 3.10.1

pip 22.2.2

Comment: You have a problem with your dev tools. The computer suggested `Perhaps try: xcode-select --install`. Sounds like good advice

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the solution proposed in the output?

```
****************************************************************************
  Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
  Perhaps try: xcode-select --install
  ****************************************************************************
```

Open Terminal, and run the following:

```
xcode-select --install
```